# callback function inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function after another when the user clicks on a button using jQuery. I used a callback function inside a click event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('form');

function scaleUp(callback){

    var pageWidth = $('.container').width();
    var formWidth = form.width();
    var scaleX = pageWidth*.8 / formWidth;
    var scaleamount; 

    if (pageWidth * .8 < 1200){

        scaleamount = 1.2;
    }else if(pageWidth * .8 < 1900){

        scaleamount = 1.8;
    }
    else{
        scaleamount = 2;
    }

    var scaleY = scaleX / scaleamount;

    form.attr('style', 'transform:scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ');transition : transform 1.5s ease;'
     );
    return true;
};

function getPos(){
    var formTop = form.position().top;
    var formLeft = form.position().left;
    console.log(formLeft);

};

$('.button').click(function(){

    scaleUp(getPos());

});

});
```

However I am always getting the old position value, not the new one after the form is transformed. Any ideas?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k3j910ny/1/

Comment: You cannot use a callback and a return closer in the same function and expect it to behave properly. In this situation you can use the return closer, the callback is not required here since standard on-page js is not asynchronous.

If you want to use a callback, you'd replace "return true;" with "callback(true)". And invoke scaleUp with "scaleUp(getPost)". Your callback doesn't need an argument or parenthesis, because its implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Better Answer

**A regular ol' callback won't work, because CSS transitions are asynchronous.**

The old answer used jQuery promises. However, there's an event called `transitionend` that you can add to your form. Basically, when a CSS transition finishes, it emits a `transitionend` even. The form can then call `getPos` when the transition ends. This is a lot better than using jQuery promises.

[Newest jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3j910ny/5/):

```
var form = $('form');
console.log("The old left pos is:" + form.position().left);

function scaleUp() {
    var pageWidth = $('.container').width();
    var formWidth = form.width();
    var scaleX = pageWidth * 0.8 / formWidth;
    var scaleamount;

    if (pageWidth * 0.8 < 1200) {
        scaleamount = 1.2;
    } else if (pageWidth * 0.8 < 1900) {
        scaleamount = 1.8;
    } else {
        scaleamount = 2;
    }

    var scaleY = scaleX / scaleamount;

    form.attr('style', 'transform:scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ');transition : transform 1.5s ease;');
}

form.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.propertyName.toLowerCase() === 'transform') {
        return getPos();
    }
});

function getPos() {
    var formTop = form.position().top;
    var formLeft = form.position().left;

    console.log("The new left pos is:" + form.position().left);
}

$('button').on('click', scaleUp);
```

## Older Answer

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3j910ny/4/). It uses jQuery promises:

```
var form = $('form');
console.log("The old left pos is:" + form.position().left);

function scaleUp() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var pageWidth = $('.container').width();
    var formWidth = form.width();
    var scaleX = pageWidth * 0.8 / formWidth;
    var scaleamount;

    if (pageWidth * 0.8 < 1200) {
        scaleamount = 1.2;
    } else if (pageWidth * 0.8 < 1900) {
        scaleamount = 1.8;
    } else {
        scaleamount = 2;
    }

    var scaleY = scaleX / scaleamount;

    form.attr('style', 'transform:scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ');transition : transform 1.5s ease;');

    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 1600); // needs to wait for the animation to complete

    return deferred.promise()
}

function getPos() {
    var formTop = form.position().top;
    var formLeft = form.position().left;

    console.log("The new left pos is:" + form.position().left);
}

$('button').on('click', function () {

    $.when(scaleUp()).then(getPos);

});
```

The animation happens asynchronously, so there's a `setTimeout` that resolves a promise a bit after the animation has finished happening. Once the promise resolves, `$.when` calls `getPos`. It's kind of hacky, but that's because of the asynchronous nature of changing the `style` attribute and giving it a CSS animation.

**In other words, because the animation is asynchronous, you need to wait for it to finish before you can call the callback and get the new position. Promises wait for an asynchronous event to finish, and then call the callback.**

If you're unfamiliar with promises, I would suggest reading the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) about the topic, and also searching for "javascript promises" on Google. It's a whole other subject.

## Original Answer

You're passing in the called version of the function as a callback (and in `scaleUp` you never even used the callback), so it doesn't see the callback as a function reference.

Do this:

```
function scaleUp(callback) {
    // all your code... then

    return callback(); // or just callback() without the return
}

$('.button').on('click', scaleUp.bind(null, getPos));
```

If you pass in `getPos()`, you're passing in the *return value* of `getPos`, not the function reference itself. By the way, the above click handler is abbreviated. You could also do:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    scaleUp(getPos);
});
```

Comment: thank you Josh! I added callback(); to the end of my scaleUp function and changed scaleUp(getPos()) to scaleUp(getPos), but still getting the old value :(

Comment: @bunnyHat, no prob. Sorry you're still having issues. Would you mind making a jsfiddle? That way it'll be easier for us to see what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: Just added the jsfiddle link to my post!

Comment: Very nice! I guess one thing i don't quite understand is the setTimeout function, what exactly does it do here and whey does it have to be 1600ms?

Comment: @bunnyHat, setTimeout forces the resolution of the promise to occur after the CSS animation has taken place (in 1600 milliseconds). The animation takes ~1500 milliseconds to happen (1.5 seconds), but in real life, the animation will take a bit longer. So we say 1600ms in the setTimeout just to be safe. **Stay tuned, I'm about to post a better answer that doesn't use the jQuery promises API**.

Comment: @bunnyHat haha no problem I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a callback.  You're calling `getPos()` *first* and passing its result to `scaleUp`.  Then within `scaleUp` you're not actually *doing anything* with that result.

If you want it to be a callback, just pass the function reference:

```
scaleUp(getPos);
```

Then, within `scaleUp`, invoke the function:

```
calllback();
```

Of course, since you're not doing anything asynchronous, you don't need to do all that.  Just call the function *after* you do your scaling:

```
scaleUp();
getPos();
```